# functional way to iterate 3 nested arrays

Tags: javascript

I have a data structure that looks like this:

```
{
  sections: [
    {
      pages: [
        {
          questions: [

          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

There's data in the questions array that I'm trying to get at, and return a final 1 dimensional array at the end. There can be an `x` number of sections, each section can have an `x` number of pages, and each page can have an `x` number of questions.

I'm trying to keep the code relatively concise but also readable, this is my current implementation:

```
function generateQuestionData(survey) {
    let data = [];

    survey.sections.forEach((section) => {
        section.pages.forEach((page) => {
            const newData = page.questions.map(getQuestionDataItem);
            data = [...data, ...newData];
        });
    });

    return data;
}
```

**EDIT**

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without the `data` variable reassignment? so something along the lines of

```
function generateQuestionData(survey) {
    return survey.sections.forEach((section) => { // something instead of forEach
        section.pages.forEach((page) => page.questions.map(getQuestionDataItem));
        // data = [...data, ...newData]; no need for this?
    });
}
```

if that makes sense

Comment: Not sure there is much you can do about that.... And not sure how reduce would make it more readable.

Comment: @epascarello bummer :/ I was thinking reduce can get rid of the nested `forEach` loops

Comment: You can use reduce on the outside, but all you are doing is shifting some code around.

Comment: you need 3 loops either way whatever you do

Comment: @epascarello I updated the question, I guess I was asking the wrong thing

Comment: @duxfox-- with that edit, yes, use push.... :) and that return with forEach is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

How about having a helper for iteration:

```
 function* goOver(array, key, ...keys) {
   for(const el of array) {
    if(keys.length) {
     yield* goOver(el[key] || [], ...keys);
    } else {
     yield el[key];
    }
 }
```

That can be used as:

```
const result = [...goOver(survey.sections, "pages", "questions")]
   .map(getQuestionDataItem);
```

---

concerning the second question:

> Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without the data variable reassignment?

how about:

```
  data.push(...newData);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` in order to show the intent to really do something per `section` and `page` to the likes of:

```
private generateQuestionData = (survey) =>
    survey.sections.reduce((data, section) =>
        [
          ...data,
          ...section.pages.reduce((pageData, page) =>
              [
                ...pageData,
                ...page.questions.map(getQuestionDataItem)
              ],
              []
          )
        ],
        []
    );
```

Code indentation/formatting could surely be optimized.

Answer (score 0):

```
const data = {
  sections: [
    {
      pages: [
        {
          questions: [
            "hello",
            "world"
          ],
        },
        {
          questions: [
            "foo",
            "bar"
          ]
        }
      ],
    },
  ],
};


const get = (...pathKeys) => o => pathKeys.reduce((o,k ) => o[k], o);
const flatten = (arrays) => [].concat.apply([], arrays);
const result = flatten(get("sections")(data).map(s => get("pages")(s).map(get("questions"))));
console.log(flatten(flatten(result)));
```

Note that the flatten at the end could be simplified with a flattenDeep function.

In "pseudo code" I would express your problem like that, with 
`compose` being composition left to right, and map being `fn => arr => arr.map(fn)`

```
compose(
  get("section"),
  map(compose(get("pages"), map(get("questions")))),
  flattenDeep,
);
```